# Process Builder vs Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification, design, process

I had the following two requirements to implement.

1. Change account type field on account as soon as a first opportunity is added to that account.
2. Change account type field on account as soon as opportunity is closed won.

So my query here is, if we are building a process to accommodate both the requirement and inserting millions of records to the system, what are the chances I would hit the platform limits?

Is processes truly bulkified?

I saw [this Release Note](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_process_bulkification.htm) but couldn't come to conclusion. If it's not bulkified I would go for Triggers.

Comment: Are you looking for any more detail here? It seems like this question may be too broad to answer completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically advocate that if you can do something in Salesforce in a declarative way, you probably should.

However, I think your situation is different because of the sheer volume you expect. In addition to (potentially) more robust bulkification, you will be able to achieve much better error handling through `Apex`. Errors are fairly opaque via `Process Builder` last I checked. In addition to improving message clarity, this will allow you to support partial success operations, instead of making them all or none in the case of a failure.

A fairly common pattern for mapping errors in this case would look something like:

```
try
{
    update relatedAccounts;
}
catch (DmlException dmx)
{
    Map<Id, List<Opportunity>> accountToOpportunities = new Map<Id, List<Opportunity>>();
    for (Opportunity opportunity : opportunities)
    {
        if (!accountToOpportunities.containsKey(opportunity.AccountId))
            accountToOpportunities.put(opportunity.AccountId, new List<Opportunity>();
        accountToOpportunities.get(opportunity.AccountId).add(opportunity);
    }

    for (Integer i = 0; i < dmx.getNumDml(); i++)
    {
        Account relatedAccount = relatedAccounts[dmx.getDmlIndex(i)];
        for (Opportunity opportunity : accountToOpportunities.get(relatedAccount.Id))
            opportunity.addError(dmx);
    }
}
```